# MBProgressHUD after selecting image in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, mbprogresshud

I'm selecting an image in UIImagePickerController.
After the image was selected I'm firing another `UIActionSheet` to select from

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    _selected_image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                            @"Share this photo",
                            nil];
    popup.tag = 2;
    [popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
}
```

When the user selects "Share" a long process is starting.
I want the MBProgressHUD to show during the process. I can't get progress HUD to show before stuff are starting to happen.

Tried two things:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (popup.tag == 1)
    {
    ...
    }
    else if (popup.tag == 2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)  //cancel
        {
            _selected_image = nil;
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
            [self doSharePhoto];
            return;
        }
        [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

doSharePhotos start running when the imagePicker is still showing.

Tried:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (popup.tag == 1)
    {

    }
    else if (popup.tag == 2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)  //cancel
        {
            _selected_image = nil;
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {

            [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                [self doSharePhoto];
            }];
            return;
        }
        [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

and in this case the `MBProgressHUD` inside doSharePhoto doesn't apprear at all

** EDIT **:

The code that starts the HUD is in `[self doSharePhoto]`:

```
- (void)doSharePhoto {

    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = @"Please wait...";
    HUD.delegate = self;
...
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You'd need to add the HUD to the proper view hierarchy to show it.If its behind any other view, it won't be visible.

Comment: from your code i can't see any HUD object, where do you start showing it?

Comment: what does your `MBProgressHUD` related code look like?

Comment: inside doSharePhoto - made an edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your doSharePhoto method perform the long running operation inside a seperate thread? If not it's blocking the main thread so , MBProgressHUD doesn't get a chance to show. Your `doSharePhoto` must look like this,

```
- (void)doSharePhoto {

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        // Do the long running operation here... 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
        });
    });

}
```

**EDIT:** Problem might be with the view you add your HUD to,

Change
`self.navigationController.view` to

```
self.navigationController.visibleViewController.view
```

So,

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.navigationController.visibleViewController.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: the second thing wasn't the problem but the dispatch_async sure did the trick... thanks

Comment: How would you write this in swift?

Comment: @return0 dispatch_async part of the code is same for Swift as well.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx Thanks, I wasn't aware.

Comment: @return0 however in swift version you will not be using caret ( ^ ) symbol in block syntax, Just remove the caret sign from above code and it will work. However, when the last argument is a block, Swift lets you put it outside the parentheses like this, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)) { 
            /*long running operation*/
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                /*hide progresshud*/
            })
        }`

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx Wow, didnt know that either, thanks so much. I am new to swift and objective c is a bit of a challenge to say the least lol Thanks again.